# Cassandra `COPY FROM`unable to coerce GMT date string to a formatted date (long)

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have been trying to use `COPY FROM` to insert into a Cassandra table that has a `timestamp` type column. However, I encountered the following error:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unable to coerce '2015-03-06 18:11:33GMT' to a  formatted date (long)"
Aborting import at record #3. Previously-inserted values still present.
0 rows imported in 0.211 seconds.
```

The content of the CSV file was actually created with a COPY TO command. My `TZ` environment variable has been set to `GMT`.

I did some searching and found a post here that mentioned using `Z` instead of `GMT` as the timezone in the data string, i.e. **'2015-03-06 18:11:33Z'**. If I replace all the `GMT` in my CSV with `Z`, `COPY FROM` worked. Link for the post here:
[unable to coerce '2012/11/11' to a formatted date (long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513447/unable-to-coerce-2012-11-11-to-a-formatted-date-long)

When I run a `SELECT` on this table, the datetime column shows up in the format of: **2015-03-06 17:53:23GMT**.

Further info, there was a bug about 'Z' timezone but it was fixed. Link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6973

So my question is, is there a way that I can run `COPY TO` so that it writes `Z` instead of `GMT` for time zone?

Alternatively, is there a way I can make `COPY FROM` work with `GMT`?

Thanks.

**Note: The solution is in the comment from @Aaron for this post. Yes, it's a hack but it works.**

Comment: I almost don't want to tell you this, because it's a terrible solution...  But if you just remove the % and leave a capital Z at the end of your `time_format`, COPY TO will drop the time zone and stick a Z on the end of all your timestamps.

Comment: I like creative ideas like this! I think I'll try this as the last resort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening here, is that you are getting bit by your `time_format` property in your `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` file.  `COPY` uses this setting when exporting your timestamp data during a `COPY TO`.  CQLSH uses the [Python strftime formats](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).  It is interesting to note that the lowercase %z and uppercase %Z seem to represent your problem.

When I `SELECT` timestamp data with %Z (upper), it looks like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm posts1;

 userid | posttime               | postcontent  | postid
--------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------
      1 | 2015-01-25 13:25:00CST |    blahblah5 | 13218139-991c-4ddc-a11a-86992f6fed66
      1 | 2015-01-25 13:22:00CST |    blahblah2 | eacdebcc-35c5-45f7-9374-d5fd987e699f
      0 | 2015-03-12 14:10:00CDT |  sdgfjdsgojr | 82766df6-4cca-4ad1-ae59-ba4488103da4
      0 | 2015-03-12 13:56:00CDT | kdsjfsdjflds | bd5c2be8-be66-41da-b9ff-98e9a4836000
      0 | 2015-03-12 09:10:00CDT |  sdgfjdsgojr | 6865216f-fc4d-431c-8067-c27cf20b6be7
```

When I try to `INSERT` a record using that date format, it fails:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO posts1 (userid,posttime,postcontent,postid) VALUES (0,'2015-03-12 14:27CST','sdgfjdsgojr',uuid());
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unable to coerce '2015-03-12 14:27CST' to a  formatted date (long)"
```

But when I alter `time_format` to use the (lowercase) %z the same query produces this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm posts1;

 userid | posttime                 | postcontent  | postid
--------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------
      1 | 2015-01-25 13:25:00-0600 |    blahblah5 | 13218139-991c-4ddc-a11a-86992f6fed66
      1 | 2015-01-25 13:22:00-0600 |    blahblah2 | eacdebcc-35c5-45f7-9374-d5fd987e699f
      0 | 2015-03-12 14:10:00-0500 |  sdgfjdsgojr | 82766df6-4cca-4ad1-ae59-ba4488103da4
      0 | 2015-03-12 13:56:00-0500 | kdsjfsdjflds | bd5c2be8-be66-41da-b9ff-98e9a4836000
      0 | 2015-03-12 09:10:00-0500 |  sdgfjdsgojr | 6865216f-fc4d-431c-8067-c27cf20b6be7
```

I can also `INSERT` data in this format:

```
INSERT INTO posts1 (userid,posttime,postcontent,postid) 
VALUES (0,'2015-03-12 14:27-0500','sdgfjdsgojr',uuid());
```

It also appears in this way when I run a `COPY TO`, and a `COPY FROM` of the same data/file also works.

In summary, check your `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` and make sure that you are either using the default setting, or this setting in the `[ui]` section:

```
[ui]
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
```

It won't get you the 'Z' like you asked for, but it will allow you to `COPY TO/FROM` your data without having to muck with the CSV file.

**Edit**

For those of you poor souls out there using CQLSH (or Cassandra, God help you) on Windows, the default location of the `cqlshrc` file is `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\.cassandra\cqlshrc`.

**Edit - 20150903**

Inspired by this question, I submitted a patch ([CASSANDRA-8970](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8970)) to allow users to specify a custom time format with `COPY`, and it was marked as "Ready To Commit" yesterday.  Basically, this patch will allow this problem to be solved by doing the following:

```
COPY posts1 TO '/home/aploetz/posts1.csv' WITH DELIMITER='|' AND HEADER=true 
    AND TIME_FORMAT='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ;
```

**Edit - 20161010**

The COPY command was [improved in Cassandra 2.2.5](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy), and the `TIMEFORMAT` option has been renamed to `DATETIMEFORMAT`.

From [New options and better performance in cqlsh copy](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy):

> DATETIMEFORMAT, which used to be called TIMEFORMAT, a string containing the Python strftime format for date and time values, such as ‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z’. It defaults to the time_format value in cqlshrc.

Comment: Good to see you here again Bryce. I tried this, putting `time_format` in my cqlshrc file. However, the `select` results I got still had `GMT` rather than `-0000` attached to the end of timestamps... Not sure if this is because I'm running my Cassandra on a Windows machine... Let me do some more digging on this.

Comment: @Will That *is* weird.  I tried it on one of my Windows boxes, too, and had similar results.  I was able to get rid of the timezone all together (just by removing the `%Z`) but that's probably not the solution you want, either.

Comment: Thanks Bryce. Good to know it's not because I'm not doing something wrong here.