# How to convert the timestamp in cassandra

Tags: date, cassandra

I am new to **cassandra**.Please guide me.
From text file I want to load data into cassandra.
One of the field in the text file is "11.09.2016 00:00:00".(which is in date.month.year HH:mm:ss) format.

While creating the DB schema I've given the datatype as timestamp. which expect

```
yyyy.mm.date HH:mm:ss.
```

How can convert that.When load the data into **cassandra** it should not mismatch.

Thnaks
Khumar

Comment: What you are using to load the data into cassandra ?
Please mention the cassandra version you are using

Comment: dse 3.2 version

Comment: using script i want to load data into cassandra.

Comment: COPY db.table_name 'aaa.csv'.Here one of the field in cs file is "11.09.2016 00:00:00".When I load data with same format will cassandra accepts it.Or do i need to change it to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

Comment: If yes how can i change the format

Comment: yes you have to change it you can use python to read data from file. read the date time column as a datetime object in python and then convert it into required format and then use python cassandra driver to insert it into cassandra 

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
You can have look on this docs for using datetime in python

Comment: DSE 3.2 is an old version of Cassandra (1.2 at its core).  If you upgrade, newer versions of Cassandra allow you to specify a `TIME_FORMAT` or `DATETIMEFORMAT` in your cqlshrc file to convert different timestamp formats at import time.  See this question for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016768/cassandra-copy-fromunable-to-coerce-gmt-date-string-to-a-formatted-date-long

Comment: In newer version of DSE, you don't need to specify or convert.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution is that, just go to your root directory and search for .cassandra folder and paste your cqlshrc.sample file which should be inside your cassandra conf directory.

And rename it to cqlshrc.

Inside it you will find the [ui] section.

Uncomment the datetimeformat field and change it to

time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Then it should work fine.
I am using cassandra 3.11.2(latest).

See documentation for details.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html

Answer (score -2):

You can change the format in your script you can use python to do that easily or shell script if you are expert in it(i am not).