# Cassandra not able to import timestamp precision correctly

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have data in CSV file which I need to import to Cassandra table. I am unable to store timestamp data column with required precision.

For example I have timestamp value in format `'06-Nov-17 05.02.33.233 AM'`. To import such data I have gone through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016768/cassandra-copy-fromunable-to-coerce-gmt-date-string-to-a-formatted-date-long). I was successfully able to import and export in my required format with the help of above link.

The issue is when I exported the data stored in Cassandra table instead of `'06-Nov-17 05.02.33.233 AM'`, I got `'06-Nov-17 05.02.33.000 AM'`. It was similar for all entries.

What is the best way to import such data to Cassandra table so that precision is maintained?

Comment: How did you export the data?

Comment: I exported using COPY to command in CSV format.