# Cassandra/Apache Nifi: Unable to coerce 'yyyy-MM-dd HH' to a formatted date (long)

Tags: date, cassandra, formatting, timestamp, apache-nifi

I m having some issues with converting a regular timestamp in **cassandra** with **Apache Nifi**.

My use case is following:

I have a csv file with a date in it looking like this ('**2015010109**') and I want to put it in cassandra by converting this string ('**2015010109**') to an proper format: **2015-01-01 09:00** -> **yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm** (I dont exactly need the minutes, but I guess it is more useful for later usage)

So far I got this propertie in my UpdateAttribute processor when trying to convert this string to a timestamp:

**date : ${csvfiledate:toDate("yyyyMMddHH","GMT"):format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH")}**

but then there is an error occuring in my PutCassandraQL processor: **Unable to coerce '2015-01-01-09' to a formatted date (long).**

I tried something along

**date : ${csvfiledate:toDate("yyyyMMddHH","GMT"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mmZ")}** aswell, but the same error is occuring.

It seems like you need to have a specific timestamp type for cassandra as you can see here:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html
But it isnt working so far, maybe you got some tipps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513447/unable-to-coerce-2012-11-11-to-a-formatted-date-long). I see that you have in format `HH-mm` and it must be `HH:mm`. Also try this: `${csvfiledate:toDate("yyyyMMddHH","GMT"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")}Z`

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards..

`toDate` parameters are used to describe how to parse the date. `format` function is used to describe how the date output should be. So the expression should be:

```
${csvfiledate:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd-HH','GMT'):format('yyyyMMddHH')}
```